# Issue decoding utf-8 on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, python-3.5

I'm having trouble decoding utf-8 on a raspberry pi... The same code works on my computer. But doesn't works on the raspberry. Any clue ?

On my laptop (expected output) :

```
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> b'\xc3\xa9'.decode('utf-8')
'é'
```

On a raspberrypi (unexpected output) :

```
Python 3.5.4 (default, Sep  5 2017, 18:32:10) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> b'\xc3\xa9'.decode('utf-8')
'�'
```

Comment: Is the output of the `locale` command identical?

Comment: It may be due to the use of a different console/shell on the two systems.

Comment: @hoefling Thank you ! I changed System Locales and now it works.

Comment: What do I have to do now to mark the question as solved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the locale setting on both systems. You can check this in python via:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getpreferredencoding()
UTF-8
```

One of your systems should report `UTF-8` encoding, the other not (presumably the `ISO-8859-1` instead). On Linux, check the output of the `locale` command to check for differences, then adjust the locale settings to match (via `localectl` or `update-locale` or whatever your distro offers).